# DateTime to string PHP

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, format, explode

I got a problem , i'm trying separate my datetime value (in bdd) with PHP

```
 $temps[0]['Date_deb']; // --> "2017-10-07 00:00:00" 


 $letemps = $temps[0]['Date_deb'];
//echo $letemps->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

 $t1 = explode(" ", $letemps);    // t1=["", ""]
 $t1[0]= $dateDebut;              // t1[0]=[""]
 $t1[1]= $dateFin;                // t1[1]=[""]
```

I think the explode doesn't work because it's a datetime format, so i tried to echo

```
//echo $letemps->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

but i got an error : Call to a member function format() on string

How can i got `t1[0]= "2017-10-07"` and `t1[1]="00:00:00"`  ?

I hope you can help me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are assigning a value to the array when it should be the other way around.

Assuming you don't have anything between `$t1` and `$dateDebut`/`$dateFin` in your actual code, then your code is going to assign the value of null to `$t1[0]` and `$t1[1]`.

Try this code where the `$dateDebut` and `$dateFin` are now equal to the date / time respectively.

```
 $temps[0]['Date_deb']; // --> "2017-10-07 00:00:00" 


 $letemps = $temps[0]['Date_deb'];

 $t1 = explode(" ", $letemps);
 $dateDebut = $t1[0];              // $dateDebut = "2017-10-07"
 $dateFin = $t1[1];                // $dateFin = "00:00:00"

 echo $dateDebut . " and " . $dateFin;
 echo "<br>"
 echo $t1[0] . " and " . $t1[1];
```

Comment: NP. Glad I could help!

Comment: Do you know why t1 is empty when i var dump $t1 after $t1 = explode(" ", $letemps);    //  
the explode function should return "2011-33-33","00:00:65" or something like that ?

Comment: check to make sure `$temps[0]['Date_deb'];` has a value.

Comment: ohw sorry my comment was too old, i didn't check the dump of t1 ^^' thanks you again for your help !!

Comment: @Marshe78 np :)